# NSString question in ObjectiveC

Tags: nsstring

I don't understand this line of code: if ([@"+/-" isEqual:operation])

where operation is an NSString (and that operation can be either a "+" a "-" or
a "/"). How is it possible to check for them all at once without getting an error?

Thanks, 
-z

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I was missing a button that corresponds to that string, please ignore

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. **isEqual** compares a string to an object, and will return NO if the object is not a string.
If you wish to compare strings use **isEqualToString**. But that will compare "+/-" to operation.
To see if operation is one of +, -, or / you would have to check each character in turn, or use a regular expression, or something like this

```
NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-/"]];

if ([operatin rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"This string does not contain +-/ characters");
}
```

Comment: Dear svenito,  Glad I asked after all. It turns out that my calculator button (and operation) was supposed to contain the string "+/-"; but I didn't know about NSCharacterSet, and will certainly be able to use this in the future. Thanks! -z